# JPA/Hibernate: how to automatically update fields on entity update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Camel and JPA to persist entities to a Postgres DB. In each entity I have a field called "history" which contains all the old values of the given entity. I'm looking for a way to populate this field automatically before each update operations. 
Surfing the web, I've found the JPA interceptors, but I've seen that they are used for auditing/logging purposes. Am I wrong? 
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you plan to store the changes in one column?

Comment: @Funtik it's a json field, handled by default by postgres

Comment: I think you could use a db trigger also.

Comment: I'd prefer to have more control in the application

Comment: Did you check [Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) already? It's the common way for creating a history in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA/Hibernate interceptors (which one depends on the version you're using) are one way to do this. Auditing/logging are similar to what you want to do, i.e. automatically update some column/property when the entity itself is updated (any property). Just note that manual update queries circumvent those interceptors so those should be avoided.

How you use those interceptors depends on how you want to implement that history functionality though. If you're doing it by generating some string/byte representation and storing it in a column it should work. If you're planning to create another entity etc. you might have to collect the changes/old values in the interceptor and upon successful commit you store the collected values. AFAIK it's not possible (at least not easy) to create a new entity when the interceptors have been invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For "manual update queries" you mean a query performed directly on the DB (not using the application)? In this case, I can get rid of this.

Comment: @dylaniato I mean any query (JPQL/HQL or SQL) directly invoked on the entity manager. For the interceptors to work you have to let Hibernate figure out the changes and trigger the queries, at least that's what we learned from our tests/implementations so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entities")    
public class Entity {
  ...

  private Date created;
  private Date updated;

  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    created = new Date();
  }

  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    updated = new Date();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EntityListeners` and provide your entity Listener class to it, and you can also reuse this whenever you want

In your entity Listener class, you can provide callback methods with `@PrePersit, @PostPersist, @PreUpdate, @PostUpdate, @PreDelete, @PostDelete` annotations. These methods will get called automatically for their respective actions.

You can read [Spring Data JPA Auditing: Saving CreatedBy, CreatedDate, LastModifiedBy, LastModifiedDate automatically](https://programmingmitra.blogspot.in/2017/02/automatic-spring-data-jpa-auditing-saving-CreatedBy-createddate-lastmodifiedby-lastmodifieddate-automatically.html) for more details.